# GAMS: changing names of files to include in a loop

Tags: gams-math

I want to include multiple `csv` files and I want to refer to the them in a loop. All my files have systematic names: `file1.csv, file2.csv etc`.
How do I create a loop including all the files?

I am looking for something like this:

```
set j /1*10/
loop(j,
  $include "filej.csv")
```

How do I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is with the [Put Writing Facility](https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/UG_Put.html).

```
set     fn      / '1.csv' * '10.csv' /;
file    output  / output.rsp /;
put     output  /;

loop(fn, 
        put '$include file' fn.tl /);
```

This will produce a file `output.rsp` with contents:

```
$include file1.csv
$include file2.csv
...
$include file10.csv
```

Then `$include output.rsp` in the relevant `.gms` file.